# Checkboxes inside a list view - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app. My requirement is to display a list of objects which are available as Json and add a checkbox to each of the list item, when the item is checked I want to store the item in a separate local DB for future use.
This is my item template.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controls:CheckBox x:Name="Completed" />
                <Label x:Name="index" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Text="{Binding index}"
                       Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label x:Name="title"
                       Text="{Binding title}"
                       Grid.Column="2" />
                <Label x:Name="count"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Text="{Binding count}"
                       Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

this is the item source for the `ListView`.

```
SurahNames.ItemsSource = viewModel.surahs;
```

My questions are:

- How to bind the bool value of the `CheckBox`?
- Where to set the Binding Context?
- And how to get the corresponding object, so that I can add it to a list and store it in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the selected item like this

```
private object _selectedItem;
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        cast to your model
        YourModel val=(YourModel)value;
        //checked is the new proprety that you added to ur model
        val.Checked=true;
        dosmthwithvalue(val);
       //this to unselect the item in listview /remove color
        _selectedItem = null;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

and for the `CheckBox` you need to add checked property to your model.
I didn't tested it and maybe this not the optimal solution, but I think that it will do what you want.